# Removing /_ah from GAE Endpoints API

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-api, google-cloud-endpoints, app.yaml

I am creating endpoint APIs using GAE Cloud Endpoints Framework

My current app.yaml Endpoint Handler looks like

```
- url: /_ah/spi/.*
  script: main.application
```

and the api call look like
 `GET http://localhost:8080/_ah/api/proj_name/v1/api_name`

Is it possible to remove the **_ah** part of the API url?

If yes, How?

Answer (score 0):

The _ah URL is typically reserved for internal API calls.  If you are building your own custom APIs, you can select any URL you want...  You could simply add another line to app.yaml that looks like....

```
- url: /api/.*
  script: api.application
```

(I like to put APIs into a separate api.py file.  You could also leave it as main.application)

Comment: You also need to add a base_path argument to the api decorator.

Answer (score 0):

This page provides detailed configuration and deployment procedures for changing the version number of your API
https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/openapi/versioning-an-api

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible.

Based on the url you mention you seem to be using the Cloud Endpoints Frameworks v1 (deprecated, soon to be shutdown, BTW). From  [Required Files and Configuration](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/python/required_files) (where you can see the deprecation note as well):

> **Note:** In the following sections, we refer to the path/**_ah/spi**. If you have created App Engine apps that are *not* Endpoints, you may
>   be expecting the path **/_ah/api** and not the path **/_ah/spi** as
>   described above. This is not a typo: Endpoints require **/_ah/spi**!

And even after migrating to the newer version you still won't be able to get rid of the `/_ah/` portion. From [Migrating from Cloud Endpoints version 1.0](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/docs/frameworks/legacy/v1/python/migrating#migrating_from_cloud_endpoints_version_10):

> 5. In the `handlers` section in `app.yaml`, change the `url` directive from `- url: /_ah/spi/.*` to `- url: /_ah/api/.*`.